# Sort an array to have specific items first in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've got an array as such:

```
[{flag: true, other: 1},
 {flag: true, other: 2},
 {flag: false, other: 3},
 {flag: true, other: 4},
 {flag: true, other: 5},
 {flag: true, other: 6},
 {flag: false, other: 7}]
```

I want to have this:

```
[{flag: false, other: 3},
 {flag: false, other: 7},
 {flag: true, other: 1},
 {flag: true, other: 2},
 {flag: true, other: 4},
 {flag: true, other: 5},
 {flag: true, other: 6}]
```

Basically I want that if `array[2].flag === false` (or any other value I choose) the matching element gets placed first in the array, but after previous matching elements.
The elements that do not match, remain in the same order they were in originally.

Order of appearance is important.

How to do this best in JavaScript?

Comment: What about the order of elements with `flag` of `false`, relative to each other?

Comment: @amn: The order they are "prefixed" to the array should be the order they got encountered in the original array.

Comment: @amn: The question states that the elements that doesn't match the condition remains in the same order as originally, and I assume that it should also apply to the elements that does match the condition.

Comment: @Guffa Yes, the question has been edited to address my valid concerns :-) But also a lot of good answers have been added in the meantime, so I retire...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't actually sorting. You can just loop through the array twice and build a new array:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].flag === false) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (!arr[i].flag === false) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

You can also do it with two result arrays and one loop, and concatenate the results:

```
var result1 = [], result2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].flag === false) {
    result1.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    result2.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
var result = result1.concat(result2);
```

Answer (score 51):

The [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) introduced with ECMAScript6 (e.g., `[...object]`) makes this relatively straightforward using an Array's `reduce` method:

```
const arr = [
  { flag: true, other: 1 },
  { flag: true, other: 2 },
  { flag: false, other: 3 },
  { flag: true, other: 4 },
  { flag: true, other: 5 },
  { flag: true, other: 6 },
  { flag: false, other: 7 }
];

const sortedArr = arr.reduce((acc, element) => {
  if (!element.flag) {
    return [element, ...acc];
  }
  return [...acc, element];
}, []);
```

I found this [example of extended parameter handling](http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator) really helpful.

Comment: isn't the reduce method missing a second argument (initialValue)?, in this case an empty array. Shouldn't this be? ```arr.reduce((acc, element) => {}, [])```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Without an initialValue supplied after the callback function, `reduce` will use the first element in the array as the initial value versus an empty array object. I have updated my code block to reflect the method signature.

Comment: this code looks amazing, nothing much to add, but it reads so much better than the 2 array looping solution above

Comment: This is a very expensive way to do it. `const rebuiltArray = [...acc.filter(elem => elem.flag), ...acc.filter(elem => !elem.flag)]` ([see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071369/5125537)) is much nicer to read and **proves to be 20x faster than your method**, according to my measures.

Comment: This does not seem to maintain the order of the elements with flag value false

Answer (score 40):

A simpler and more elegant way to do is by building a new array by filtering the old one twice: once filtered by `flag: true` and once by `flag: false`. All together it would look like:

```
// THE INITIAL ARRAY:
const originalArray = [
    {flag: true, other: 1},
    {flag: true, other: 2},
    {flag: false, other: 3},
    {flag: true, other: 4},
    {flag: true, other: 5},
    {flag: true, other: 6},
    {flag: false, other: 7}
];

// THE SORTED ARRAY:
const sortedArray = [
    ...originalArray.filter(({flag}) => flag),
    ...originalArray.filter(({flag}) => !flag)
];
```

In my opinion it is way easier for a human to read than using *comparer* or *reducer* functions, and (based on measurements) it is also a pretty well-performing solution.

---

### A performance comparison:

I saw that [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551373/5125537) using `arr.reduce()` performs around 20x slower than this solution. I used [ES6 Console](https://es6console.com/) for comparison, feel free to test it yourself too!

#### Measuring the `array.reduce()` way:

```
const arr = [
  { flag: true, other: 1 },
  { flag: true, other: 2 },
  { flag: false, other: 3 },
  { flag: true, other: 4 },
  { flag: true, other: 5 },
  { flag: true, other: 6 },
  { flag: false, other: 7 }
];

// Lets multiple the array items 11 times to increase the looping process:
new Array(11).fill().forEach(x => arr.push(...arr));

console.time();

const reducedArr = arr.reduce((acc, element) => {
  if (element.flag === false) {
    return [element, ...acc];
  }
  return [...acc, element];
}, []);

console.timeEnd(); // RESULTS: between 285-350ms
```

#### Measuring the `array.filter()` way:

```
const arr = [
  { flag: true, other: 1 },
  { flag: true, other: 2 },
  { flag: false, other: 3 },
  { flag: true, other: 4 },
  { flag: true, other: 5 },
  { flag: true, other: 6 },
  { flag: false, other: 7 }
];

// Lets multiple the array items 11 times to increase the looping process:
new Array(11).fill().forEach(x => arr.push(...arr));

console.time();

const rebuiltArray = [
  ...arr.filter(x => x.flag),
  ...arr.filter(x => !x.flag)
];

console.timeEnd(); // RESULTS: between 6-20ms
```

Comment: Hi Norbert, thanks for this! May I ask you why you are casting that true/false flag with a `!!` to be a boolean?

Comment: @Rogier nice catch, actually it is completely unnecessary! I updated my answer :)

Comment: Easier to read and better performing. Thanks mate :D

Answer (score 27):

Write a custom sort function that uses the flag to increase the sort priority:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (!a['flag'] && b['flag'])
    return 1;
  if (a['flag'] && !b['flag'])
    return -1;
  return a['other'] - b['other']
});
```

Basically, I'm assuming that an entry in the list with the flag set takes priority over an item without the flag.  So if a doesn't have the flag set and b does, return 1 (select b).  If a does and b doesn't return -1 (select a).

In the case where both have the flag set or both don't, cmp as normal.

Comment: Hey can you please explain how it actually works as it's difficult to analyse on browser's console.

Comment: Sure,  I've added a comment.

Comment: Simple and easy to understand, also very effective. Thank you for sharing the algorithm with explanations.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. It's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a little simple. 
Because javascript treats true as 1 and false as 0 you can use them to create a comparator like this,

```
var comp = function(a,b){
    return a.flag*1 - b.flag*1;
}
```

and then you can use this comparator to sort the array

```
var arr = [{flag: true, other: 1},
         {flag: true, other: 2},
         {flag: false, other: 3},
         {flag: true, other: 4},
         {flag: true, other: 5},
         {flag: true, other: 6},
         {flag: false, other: 7}];
arr.sort(comp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sort with the deltas of the values.

1. Sort by `flag`. The boolean values are converted to `1`, if `true` or `0`, if `false.`
2. Sort by `other`.

```js
var array = [{flag: true, other: 1 }, { flag: true, other: 2 }, { flag: false, other: 3 }, { flag: true, other: 4 }, { flag: true, other: 5 }, { flag: true, other: 6 }, { flag: false, other: 7 }];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    a.flag - b.flag ||
    a.other - b.other
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort method can take an optional sortFunction as a parameter that you can use to define the ordering of elements after the sort

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select certain array items but keep them in their original order, you want the `filter()` method. This function is an [extension to the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), so you may need to use the shim provided at that page depending on what browsers you’re supporting.

(When I first read your question I thought that you wanted to sort based on the flag, and then based on value; for that you could use the built-in `sort()` method.)

```
var input = [{flag: true, other: 1},
             {flag: true, other: 2},
             {flag: false, other: 3},
             {flag: true, other: 4},
             {flag: true, other: 5},
             {flag: true, other: 6},
             {flag: false, other: 7}]
var false_items = input.filter(
        function(val, idx, arr) {
            return (val["flag"] == false);
        });
var true_items = input.filter(
        function(val, idx, arr) {
            return (val["flag"] == true);
        });

var sorted = false_items.concat(true_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to sort the array on the basis of `flag` and then by the `other`

```js
var a = [{flag: true, other: 1},
 {flag: true, other: 2},
 {flag: false, other: 3},
 {flag: true, other: 4},
 {flag: true, other: 5},
 {flag: true, other: 6},
 {flag: false, other: 7}];

a.sort((a, b)=> a.flag - b.flag).sort((a,b) => a.other - b.other);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) { // sort the array using a custom function,
                                // which is called a number of times to
                                // determine the new order. a and b are two
                                // elements to compare. JavaScript uses the
                                // return value to determine the new order:
                                // 1  - a should come later than b
                                // -1 - a should come earlier than b
                                // 0  - they should stay in their current order
    return a.flag === true && b.flag === false
            ? 1 // if a is true and b is false a should come later on
            : a.flag === false && b.flag === true
               ? -1 // if a is false and b is true a should come earlier
               : a.other > b.other
                  ? 1 // if a.other > b.other, a must come later on
                  : a.other < b.other
                    ? -1 // if a.other < b.other, a must come earlier
                    : 0; // otherwise they are equal, so they have no order difference
});
```