# MongoDB Sort certain Documents to top first

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting

Let's say I have the following collection

```
Collection = [
    {name: 'Ann'},
    {name: 'Bob'},
    {name: 'Cecil'},
    {name: 'KEY: John'},
    {name: 'KEY: Cecil'},
    {name: 'Susan'},
    {name: 'Zack'}
];
```

Is there any way to use `sort` in `MongoDB` so that I can have all `Documents` that have their `name` field start with `KEY:` get returned first? And then I'd like the rest of the `Collection` to be sorted how it currently is.

I.e

```
Collection = [
        {name: 'KEY: John'},
        {name: 'KEY: Cecil'},
        {name: 'Ann'},
        {name: 'Bob'},
        {name: 'Cecil'},
        {name: 'Susan'},
        {name: 'Zack'}
    ];
```

From what I've read there's no way to do a custom sort in MongoDB. If not, is there a simple way to do this in JS using `underscore` or some other library. I'd prefer that than the accepted answer here [Sort an array to have specific items first in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974069/sort-an-array-to-have-specific-items-first-in-the-array) where another array(s) has to be built.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a custom compare function with array.sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to evaluate new field your collection will be sorted by. The [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/index.html) operator can be used to determine if string starts with `KEY`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            startsWithKey: { $eq: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$name", "KEY", 0 ] } ]}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            startsWithKey: -1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OHkB-Hfk1Tb)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this without an aggregation ?

Comment: no, you have to use `$addFields` which is only available under `,aggregate()`. Is that a problem?

Comment: Not inherently a problem, just that aggregates are a pain in the framework I'm using (Meteor)