# How to get the list of names from the array in an alphabetical order but wanted a specific user first in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array that has list of all the names sorted alphabetically. but the issue here is out of the items in the array i need the user who logged in should appear first in the array and then followed by the rest in the alphabetical order.

```
const getSortedFullNames = (
  ownerUsers: GetUsersRes,
  ownerUserNames: { [ownedBy: string]: string },
  userSettings?: UserSettings
): OwnerName[] => {
  if (userSettings === undefined) return [];
  const sortedArray = ownerUsers.sort((a, b) =>
  a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)
  );
  return sortedArray.map(
    (owner: OwnerMeta) =>
      ({
        userId: owner.id,
        name: ownerUserNames[owner.id],
      } as OwnerName)
  );  
};
```

The output of this array is
[Int amp
Inti Broker
Timothy Gibson]

But Inti broker is the user who logged in and he should appear first in the array followed by rest. So expected output of the array is
[Int Broker
Inti amp
Timothy Gibson]

Can anyone help with this as i am new to react.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array to have specific items first in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974069/sort-an-array-to-have-specific-items-first-in-the-array)

Comment: How do you know if the user is logged in?

Comment: Yes that could answer my questions... Thank you